# How to get all cachegroup names in TimesTen IMDB?

Tags: oracle, timesten

We can get all cache groups names and their status from **cachegroups** command.

Is there any system/user tables exist from which we can query cache group names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info about *cache groups*, take a look at the doc for **SYS.CACHE_GROUP**.

For info about *cached tables*, take a look at the doc for **SYS.TABLES**.

Both are in the doc "**System Tables and Views Reference**".